# Função "strstr()" não está localizando o que espero

Tags: c, array, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for)){
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela forma como está lendo o texto (que não é o mais aconselhável) ele está colocando o caractere de fim de linha dentro da *string*, aí vai procurar pelo texto c/ o fim de linha e não vai achar. Precisa encerrar a *string* quando encontrar este caractere, assim a busca será feita só no texto. Para isso precisa acrescentar este código antes de usar a *string*:

```
search_for[strcspn(search_for, "\n")] = 0;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LqxxrS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tevpkado-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Find.c).